# Is a "cathode ray drive" feasible?

Tags: rocket-science, graphene, propulsion

When I saw the headline, [Fuel Free Spacecrafts Using Graphene](http://science.slashdot.org/story/15/06/01/2215216/fuel-free-spacecrafts-using-graphene), I thought it was another reactionless drive, but it turned out to be a bit more plausible :)

Original paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04254). Long story short, researchers shone a laser on some graphene sponge material and it unexpectedly moved. It seems to work by emitting electrons. But what I wonder is, if electron emission is a viable means of space propulsion, and we've had the technology to create electron beams since at least the invention of television, why isn't a "cathode ray drive" a thing already? A CRT can generate 20 KeV electrons ([source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ev.html)), vs. about 70 eV for the graphene sponge. Charge neutralization would be an issue, but I suppose there are enough electrons floating around in space (due to solar wind etc.) to do the job? As the spacecraft acquired a more positive charge, it would "vacuum up" electrons from a larger area, eventually reaching equilibrium with the electrons being emitted. I just wonder if this equilibrium charge would make the drive too inefficient.

Comment: I don't think that there would be enough.

Comment: Your spacecraft has a capacitance of couple hundred pF to a few nF, at most. A 1mA electron beam will charge that capacitance to 20kV in a mere 20kV*1nF/1mA=0.2s, after that the current flow will stop. The only positive charges that you have to neutralize the space charge are ions, so you might as well use their much larger mass to develop more momentum change for the same amount of energy, hence we are building ion-drives rather than electron drives. The electron gun is still needed... to neutralize the space charge built up by the ions, but it doesn't add much to the propulsion.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you would not have as much thrust but it would be more than a EM drive and fuel would only be limited to the amount of electrons within the system, and lets say you built an aircraft in the future with a nuclear reactor that produces for our purposes unlimited power than a highly inefficient CRT drive may actually be practical considering that the electrons exiting the CRT would be traveling near the speed of light.

Comment: An electron gun doesn't _make_ electrons: The electrons have to come from the ship itself. And, they are negatively charged particles, so as you shoot them away from the ship, the ship becomes positively charged.  It only takes a fraction of a second before the positive charge on the ship becomes so great that the gun can no longer give electrons enough energy to escape.  They just come right back, and you end up with no net thrust.  Read @CuriousOne 's comment for details and, to see how a particle accelerator _can_ be used to propel a spacecraft.

Comment: what if you incorporated a beta emitting radioactive element as part of the cathode, and even if you didn't incorporate any radioactive material into the cathode it would be the only part of the ship to become positively charged once depleted of enough electrons.

Comment: Re, a beta emitter:  OK, I stand corrected, that _does_ make electrons, but the lifetime total number of electrons it can make is only equal to the number of atoms of the radioactive nuclide.  If you could strip one electron from every atom in the whole ship (which you could not, because of the charge problem), that would only amount to a tiny, tiny fraction of the ship's mass.

Comment: Confining the accumulated positive charge to a small part of the ship doesn't solve the problem:  The electrons that you shoot out the back of the ship will be attracted just as strongly to the positive charge regardless of how the positive charge is distributed.

Comment: Neodymium with negative pole facing cathode? Also, a standard TV CRT will last for several years with theoretically no source of electrons simply do to the shear amount of electrons per gram of mater.

Comment: Electrons in a CRT display flow in a _[circuit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/circuit?s=t)_.